# Reinstall Mac OSX on Ubuntu Macbook

Tags: macos, startup, unix

Last year I installed Ubuntu on my 2006 MacBook (Intel), and erased the hard drive with MacOSX 10.5 in the process. Linux was fun, but now I want another Mac to play around with.

I've put 10.8's install files on a flash drive and rebooted (holding `option`), but this brings up the Linux drive selector, and I do not see my flash drive as an option.

How can I go about installing 10.9 on my MacBook?

---

Update: I've now got 10.8 on my flash drive. When I load Startup Manager, I see 3 options:

1. `Windows`, which actually takes me to Ubuntu.
2. `EFI Boot` which produces a "no" symbol and then the computer shuts down.
3. `rEFIt`

I've got rEFIt running through my optical drive. When I select this, I get three primary choices:

1. `Boot Mac OSX from Mac OSX Install ESD`: "no" symbol
2. `Boot boot.efi from Mac OS X Install ESD`: "no" symbol
3. `Boot Linux from HD`: Linux boots as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Mavericks on a 2006 MacBook.

> To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:
>
> - iMac (Mid-2007 or later)
> - MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
> - MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
> - MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
> - Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
> - Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
> - Xserve (Early 2009)

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5842</sup>

Comment: Fine. I have 10.8 available also. Is this why the disk is unrecognized?

Comment: @gmacfarlane What method did you use to put the 'install files' on your flash drive? It should have seen the drive, but not been able to boot from it.

Comment: I used Disk Utility to execute the instructions here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-to-install-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: I used this same flash drive to do a clean install on a 2012 MacBook Pro two weeks ago.

Comment: @gmacfarlane Indeed, it should have seen the drive with the ⌥-boot. C-boot won't boot from a USB. Holding a key on boot intercepts the boot at firmware level and shouldn't have any impact on the OS that is installed. It'll even work if you don't have an OS installed.

Comment: See updates to question.